# Changing spaces into dashes in Plain-TeX

Tags: plain-tex

In Plain-TeX, how can I change a string that is stored in a macro so that each space in that string is turned into a dash? E.g. if `\def\a{This little example}`, I will like to have some procedure that applied to `\a` returns "This-little-example". I know I can use `\obeyspaces` to do the trick on a literal string,

```
\def\a{This little example}
{\obeyspaces\let =-%
1. This is a test, only a   test.
2. \a
}
\bye
```

yet that trick does not work on the string stored in macro `\a` (that is, the expansion of `\a` above is not modified, yet the first line does change into "1.-This-is-a-test,-only-a---test.").

I also tried changing the space's catcode as in

```
\begingroup
\catcode` =\active
\gdef\swapSpace{%
  \catcode` =\active
  \def {-}%
}
\endgroup

 My test text...% plain text not to be changed...

{\swapSpace
3. My test text... It works, for a literal string...
}

{\swapSpace
4. \a

Yet it fails for the macro above.
}
\bye
```

But that approach also fails as `\a` is expanded after all the other things.

Comment: can' t you define `\a` when space is active, eg in the scope of `\swapspace` ?

Comment: Just to be sure: do you want that the contents of `\a` is typeset with hyphens instead of spaces or that the spaces stored in `\a` become hyphens in a context where all the spaces are turned into hyphens?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: no, I cannot define \a within the scope of \swapSpace. For a little context, I am receiving the macro \a from command line (users will run something like tex '\def\a{Blah blah}\input{program}' then within program the value of \a is used (if defined). \a is used as is, and after its spaces are swapped for dashes (so both 'Blah blah' and 'Blah-blah' are needed).

Comment: @egreg: it is more like the second option, I need the spaces stored in \a to become hyphens in a context, while in another context I need the spaces in \a to remain spaces.

Comment: @LuHe you can use the second form in my answer

Answer (score 2):

You can replace spaces in a macro already defined by another token (or token list).

```
\def\replspaces#1#2{\expandafter\replspacesA\expandafter#2#1 \end}
\def\replspacesA#1#2 #3{#2\ifx\end#3\else#1\afterfi{\replspacesA#1#3}\fi}
\def\afterfi#1#2\fi{\fi#1}

% usage: \replspaces\macro{what}
% example:

\def\a{This little example}
\replspaces\a{-}
```

The macro `\replspaces` is expandable. You can replace all spaces by another token by

```
\def\a{This little example}
\edef\a{\replspaces\a{?}}
\meaning\a % macro:->This?little?example
```

Answer (score 1):

Your original would work if `\a` was defined when space is active, so

[image]

```
{\obeyspaces\let =-%
\def\a{This little example}
1. This is a test, only a   test.
2. \a
}
\bye
```

or

```
{\obeyspaces
\gdef\a{This little example}
}


{\obeyspaces\let =-%
1. This is a test, only a   test.
2. \a
}
\bye
```

If that is not possible you could use `\scantokens` if using etex (pdftex or etex binaries)

```
\def\a{This little example}



{\obeyspaces\let =-%
1. This is a test, only a   test.
2. \scantokens\expandafter{\a}%
}
\bye
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your strings to appear in `\swapSpace` with `\scantokens` incorporated.

```
\def\specialdef#1#2{%
  \def#1{%
    \ifnum\catcode`\ =\active
      \scantokens{#2\noexpand\empty}%
    \else
      #2%
    \fi
  }%
}
\begingroup
\catcode` =\active
\gdef\swapSpace{%
  \catcode` =\active
  \def {-}%
}
\endgroup

\specialdef\a{This little example}


 My test text...% plain text not to be changed...

\a\ is good

{\swapSpace
3. My test text... It works, for a literal string...
}

{\swapSpace
4. \a is good

}

\bye
```

[image]